# Spring security oauth token extraction

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to extract my access token from Spring's security OAuth module after authentication. I have tried looking over the `Principal` object, multiple OAuth user details are displayed, yet no data on access token.

How do I retrieve the access token that Spring security module attains after OAuth authentication?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security 5's OAuth2 or spring-security-oauth2?

Comment: Try to call `getAccessToken` from the [`TokenStore`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you put Authentication authentication as argument in controller method. You can access access token from Authentication object like code below.

```
((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)((OAuth2Authentication) authentication).getDetails()).getTokenValue()
```

Comment: those classes were removed in spring security 5 Oauth2 libraries